# Getting X and Y component vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

This diagram shows that to get a component vector, you use the "SOH CAH TOA" rule in a right angle triangle,

[image]

Additionally, this is how I learned to do it many years ago.

However, in my math textbook, I often see the book calculating components with angles GREATER than 90 degrees.  How is this possible? If the angle is greater than 90 degrees, the SOH CAH TOA rule no longer applies.  I do not understand how or why they are able to use angles over 90 degrees.  Can someone shed some light on this?  For example, instead of doing $sin(60)$, and then checking which quadrant the vector component is in and multiplying it by $(-1)$, the book will literally just do $sin(240)$

Comment: This is just a question about where the function $\text{sin}$ is defined. Although, physically (as in physics, where many of these mnemonics originate in application, especially in precalculus courses) this function makes the most sense within certain bounds, depending on the context.  The general formula for, for instance, $\text{sin}$ given as $\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$ is for use with triangles, whose angles sum to $180$ degrees.  The actual definition of $\text{sin}$, which is explored in introductory analysis courses, is omitted (usually) in precalc classes.

Comment: This is where the confusion comes from - the function $\text{sin}:[0,2\pi] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is truly defined for an entire circle, not only for angles $\leq 90$ degrees.  However, $\text{sin}$ and $\text{cos}$ are horizontally symmetric under half-circles in absolute value, so this is where this $-1$ factor comes from.

Comment: My main point is that $\text{sin}$ (and $\text{cos}$ for that matter) have repeating image sets. The best way to visualize these functions in action is with a circle (define the entire plane in the context that you are trying to physically describe and examine the triangle in the plane over the unit circle, which defines the sine and cosine for every angle that can be formed in this plane).